# A pan gesture without setTranslation strange behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

My code:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let transition = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    switch gesture.state{
    case .Changed:
        if let view = gesture.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + transition.x, y: view.center.y + transition.y)
        }
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    default:break
    }
}
```

So I can drag a big button in the screen around. Everything works find till I comment out `gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)`.

I thought that one line of code only tells the app to remember the last position of the button on screen and move from there next time, but...

Then I ran the project again on a simulator, when I clicked on that button and tried to move a bit, the button just flew in the same direction and disappeared off screen, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pan around, the `transition` value is from where you first began the gesture.

Look at how you move the button. You just keep adding the larger and larger `transition` to each updated `center`. What you need to do is add the latest `transition` to the `center` as it was when the pan gesture was first recognized.

So either reset the translation (like in your posted code), or save the original `center` of the button when the gesture's state is `.Began` and apply the translation to the original center value.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the answer I'm looking for.